# udev rule not working on Arch to disable touchpad when USB mouse connected

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, udev, devices, mouse

I'm trying to write a udev rule to disable (and re-enable) my trackpad when a USB mouse is connected.

Currently, my rule looks like:

`ACTION=="add", ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="02", ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="03", ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="01", ENV{REMOVE_CMD}="/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=0", RUN+="/usr/bin/synclient TouchpadOff=1"`

and I've saved this in `/etc/udev/rules.d/99-mouse-touchpad.rules` and reloaded using `udevadm control --reload` but nothing happens when I plug/unplug my mouse at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you should use sudo your_user for the utility, or pass DISPLAY environmant variable, so it could communicate with Xorg driver. And, make sure you have synaptics driver active...

Try running synclient as root with cleared environment (simulate run by udev) - i'm guessing, it won't do anything.

Comment: This worked, thanks! I just had to pass the ENV{XAUTHORITY} and ENV{DISPLAY} arguments and it works perfectly now :D